# Pointer Increment Decrement Syntax Difference

Tags: c++, c, pointers

when I work on pointers on a website I stick at a point.

When I write the given example I can assign adresses of array on a pointer for an increment a pointer example like `ptr = arr;` and it works correctly, but when I do the same thing for the decrement example it doesn't work it works only when I write like this `ptr = &arr[2]`. Why I have to write ampersand for decrement example? what is the difference between those two?

```
int main()
{
    int arr[3]={10,20,30};
    int *ptr,i;

    ptr=arr;

    for(i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
        printf("adress of variable arr[%d] %x\n",i+1,ptr);
        printf("value of arr[%d] = %d\n",i+1,*ptr);
        ptr++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: arr[2] is of type int, you need to apply & to get its address

Comment: in C, an array degrades to its' address so getting the address is: ptr = array.  However, array[someoffset] is trying to access that actual contents of the indicated offset into the array.  To get the address of the offset into the array, the code needs to get the address via: &array[someoffset]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is that in *"decrement"* case you use `[]`. Think of `arr` as reference to whole array thus it is ok (compiler wise) to do `ptr=arr` or `ptr=&arr` with same result. On the other hand `arr[3]` is a reference to object in array, so you need to get its address explicitly (no compiler optimization for you).

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to write it, just use the pointer:

```
 ptr = var + 2 ;

for(i=0;i<3;i++)
{ 
    printf("%d" , *ptr ) ;
    ptr-- ;
```

Note that the last element is at `+2` not +3.

Comment: sorry ı wrote the codes wrong on the explanation.. ı corrected them

Answer (score 2):

in case of an `int arr[3]`, `&arr[0]` and `arr` points to the same thing, the *base address* of the array, or, the address of the first element in the array. That's why in your *increment* case, you're allowed to write `ptr = var` which is nothing but storing the starting address in a separate pointer.

In case of decrements, there is nothing which can point *directly* to the *end-of-array* element address. So , you have to use the *address-of-last-element* [`&arr[n-1]`, `n` being the size] to denote the address of the last element.